# jQuery fade in one after another with CSS

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a collection of divs fade in one after another, but having issues adding the class 'is-visible'.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jackmichael/6mb765wx/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.card').each(function (i) {
         setTimeout(function () {
            $('.card').eq(i).addclass('is-visible');
         }, 300 * i);
    });

});
```

Comment: Typo. There's a capital 'C' in `addClass()` http://jsfiddle.net/6mb765wx/4/

Comment: I'm head in hands disappointed with myself